# Don't apply the edit-every-5-second rule when last edit of same comment was rejected

Tags: bug, comments, comment-edits

Sometimes I edit a comment in a way which causes the edit to be rejected, e.g. by @-mentioning a second user. I then quickly remove the @ and try to submit the edit again, only to be rebuffed with a pop-up message telling me I can only edit a comment once every 5 seconds.

I believe that's buggy behavior, and suggest that another edit after a rejected edit would not be subject to the 5-second rule. Note that a second edit after an accepted one would still need a 5-second delay.

Comment: I'm getting the information off my elbow, but perhaps this imposition of 5 seconds for edits is a important thing like a protection against [DDoS attacks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

Comment: meh, you can just try again

Comment: It would be nice if _all_ site interactions that get canceled could avoid this 5 second delay. I have to deal with probably a dozen such cases when flagging comments or opening the close modal every single day.

Comment: @AugustoVasques The interaction that occurs here in einpoklum's scenario is client-side validation, so there shouldn't be any network load/service impact.

Comment: @TylerH. So my elbow was wrong.

Comment: @AugustoVasques: just the left elbow. The right one is spot-on.